# sending flash success message to parent tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I'm attempting to trigger a refresh of a parent window and have a flash success message appear on that window.

To clarify, a user works from an admin page, which then opens another tab with an article.   I currently have it set to submit and close, and then have the original page reload ( through `window.opener.location.reload();`

I can generate a flash success message on the current page, but of course, that's not helpful, as that page closes immediately on submit.

Is it possible to get this to show on the original tab/window using a similar process like below?

```
function refreshParent() {
    window.opener.location.reload();
    window.opener.location.$('header > .alerts').append( $('<div>Article sent to editor.</div>').addClass('alert alert-success'));
}
```

There's currently an empty `<header></header>` tag on the twig for the original window.  I'm not sure if I have the above syntax correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like

```
<script>
    window.onunload = refreshParent;triggerAlertOnParent;
    function refreshParenttriggerAlertOnParent() {
        window.opener.location.hash = "showAlert";
        window.opener.location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

in the child window to 
 1. add a #showAlert hash to the URL of window.opener
 2. ask window.opener to refresh (with the new hash in URL) to retrieve new data from server

in the parent window, always have the HTML for the alert box ready, but hide it using css

```
<div class="alert alert-success is-hidden">Article sent to editor.</div>
```

CSS:

```
.is-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

when your parent page is loaded, in your javascript code, see if there is a hash in the URL that is set to "showAlert", if so, remove the is-hidden class, so that the alert box is displayed.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if (document.location.hash === "#showAlert")
        $(".alert.is-hidden").removeClass("is-hidden");
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand.    I only want the alert to show once the event has occurred?   So basically you are saying I create a tag like `<header id="showAlert"></header>`?   Where would I put the necessary flashbag information?

Comment: @nomistic updated with a more direct method of calling a js function in parent (opener) window from child window

Comment: you removed the refresh.  Is that intentional?   I do need the page to refresh otherwise data on that page does not render properly

Comment: in that case, you will need to use my method before. let me update it again.

Comment: @nomistic does your alert message need to be dynamic or it is always the same like "Content updated"?

Comment: I don't want an alert box.  I just want a flash message as described above:  `'<div>Article sent to editor.</div>').addClass('alert alert-success')` It's static, and will always say the same thing

Comment: Thanks, got it!  (I'm actually using an onsubmit action), but this is what I wanted.)